# Inconsistency of NaN

Tags: floating-point, julia, nan

Inconsistent results under some operations involving NaN

Multiplying NaN and 0/0 by false

```
0/0 # returns NaN
NaN*false # returns 0.0
(0/0)*false # returns -0.0
```

Isn’t this an inconsistency of NaN?
Also:

```
(NaN*(0/0))*false # returns 0.0
```

but:

```
((0/0)*NaN)*false # returns -0.0
```

another inconsistency?

Comment: I mean... does anyone rely upon this behavior?

Comment: The first one makes sense since `NaN` technically has a sign which isn't shown because why would you ever want it. No clue about the second one, that's really weird

Comment: It is not Julia related I think. Operation `NaN any_op anyfloat` seems to return the first argument on assembly level. As @Oscar noted in the first case your `NaN` has a negation sign, and in the second it does not.

Comment: More problematic is this definition I think `ifelse(x, y, copysign(zero(y), y))` of multiplying `Bool` by float (and this is Julia related :)). Which means `false*NaN` is `0.0` but `true*NaN` is `NaN`. But maybe it is intended - not sure.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Indeed, it's a bit irritating that `false * NaN == 0.0`, but `0.0 * NaN == NaN`. I expected booleans to work the same as `0` or `1` in any cases...

Comment: That is actually there for a very good reason. It is needed to make sparse matrices work. Having `false` as a strong zero allows sparse multiplication the freedom to use efficient algorithms while having the same result as dense counterparts.

Comment: Cross-post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/inconsistency-of-nan/28671